# Skin Problem: Acne or Acnes?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

[image: Text]

According to Cambridge Dictionary, acne is an uncountable noun that means "a skin disease common in young people, in which small, red spots appear on the face and neck". What does the word "acnes" intended to convey when a product is an "Acnes Creamy Wash"? Different kinds of acne?

Comment: They seem to have problems with plurals: "Helps to prevent pimple" is not good English. In any case, *Acnes* could simply be a trade name; it doesn't have to be a plural.

Comment: The "helps to prevent pimple" suggests a loose usage of number on that tube, so I would not regard it as a guide to standard English.  My guess is that it was designed somewhere in Asia (Mentholatum has been a brand of Rohto Pharmaceutical Co. of Japan since the 1970s)

Answer (score 2):

In rare cases, *acnes* can be a plural form of *acne,* but that isn't what's happening here.

In this case, *Acnes* is a proper noun; it's part of the name of the product, not the name of the condition it treats. The product is made by Rohto, a Japanese brand ([see Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohto_Pharmaceutical)), which may explain the confusing labeling.

*Edit:* the typo "helps to prevent pimple" (instead of "pimples") on the upper left of the image does suggest a certain unfamiliarity with English.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are different types of acnes:

> The noun [acne](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/acne.html#:%7E:text=The%20noun%20acne%20can%20be,or%20a%20collection%20of%20acnes.) can be countable or uncountable.
>
> In more general, commonly used contexts, the plural form will also be acne.
>
> However, in more specific contexts, the plural form can also be acnes e.g. in reference to various types of acnes or a collection of acnes.

(Wordhippo.com)

For instance:

> Propionibacterium acnes and Cutibacterium acnes

Comment: Those examples are species names, not the names of medical conditions.